# Can I use a 4-pole breaker in place of a Gould 200 amp main breaker?

Tags: electrical

I have a 200 amp gould ITE 2 pole main breaker that keeps tripping, I've checked around and they are no longer produced, but I did find a 4 pole breaker. can I use this in its place?

Comment: Can you post photos of the panel in question please?

Answer (score 2):

Never, never, never mix random brand-name breakers with random-brand-name panels.  Most of the 1" wide breakers will seem to physically fit, but they won't mate properly with the buses, and will arc and burn up.  This is a death sentence for the panel, so now you're into the ~$2000 of having one replaced whole.

I get when you're dealing with an obsolete panel like ITE/Gould, Cutler Hammer, Challenger, Westinghouse, Murray, BRyant, etc. -- you go "gosh, this thing is totally unsupported, I have no choice but to root around eBay for used breakers".

Not at all.  Most old brands - and every one I listed - have been acquired and merged, and are now new-brand panels readily available at electrical supply houses.  Those six I listed are now Siemens, Eaton, Eaton, Eaton, Siemens and Eaton.

So I would call around to electrical supply houses (NOT big box stores) and find one who is a Siemens dealer.  Then come in with a photo of your panel label and of your old main breaker, especially any numbers it may have.  **It is quite possible they can hand you a new-manufacture Siemens breaker that will fit**.  They can also sell you THE correct branch circuit breakers for the panel.  Those can be worth modernizing, because  you can add AFCI or AFCI+GFCI functionality.

Comment: ..refurbished for 89.....  I knew that would get ya..lol+

Answer (score 1):

Normally the panel cover will list all the breaker styles that are *Listed* (UL,CSA,ETL) for use in the panelboard.

If there are no factors that would make you think a panel change is a good route then you may find a breaker from surplus or re-build company. Finding local surplus dealers can be a little rough, if an internet search doesn't return good results for a local source then a local electrical supply company will know who to call. Otherwise you could check Relectric.com.

Comment: Thank you, I did find a 2 pole thats been refurbished for 89.00, really did want to install a whole new box.

Comment: @RobMcDowell -- why are you not posting photos of the panel, including the labeling on the inside? (They are tremendous help to us in identifying what precisely you have, as there is a good chance breakers are still made/available for it...)